# pandas quantile comparison: indexes not aligned

Tags: pandas

Not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong here, and I'm sure there is a simple solution but much googling hasn't helped.

Here's a toy example of what I'm trying to do:

```
d = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [2,3,4,5,6], 'c':[3,4,5,6,7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d).T
```

So the table should look like:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
a  1  2  3  4  5
b  2  3  4  5  6
c  3  4  5  6  7
```

I then want to compare each column value to a quantile value per row:

```
q = df.quantile(.7, axis=1)

df > q
```

I would expect the output to show "True" in columns 3 and 4, but this is the output:

```
   0      1      2      3      4      a      b      c
a  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
b  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
c  False  False  False  False  False  False  False  False
```

I don't understand why pandas is adding the rows to the columns in this example.

thanks

Comment: Outside of what is already mentioned as the solution in the question given above, note than in your case, you could simplify things by not transposing in the first place, as you then never need to specify axes in `quantile` or `gt`. That is, if `df = pd.DataFrame(d)`, then `df > df.quantile(.7)` just works.

Comment: thanks. the link answered my question.